# Construct a focus and a directrix of the parabola $\Pi$ such that given lines $AB$ and $AC$ are tangent to $\Pi$ at points $B$ and $C$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, plane-geometry, geometric-construction

> The triangle $ABC$ is drawn on the plane. Using only a compass and a ruler, construct a focus and a directrix of the parabola $\Pi$ such that lines $AB$ and $AC$ are tangent to $\Pi$ at points $B$ and $C$ respectively.

[image]

**My work**. Let $X$ and $Y$ be the points of intersection of the directrix of the parabola $\Pi$ with the lines $AB$ and $AC$ respectively. Let $F$ be the focus of the parabola $\Pi$. I tried to apply the parabola property, which is that $\angle XFB=\angle YFC=\frac{\pi}{2}$, but didn't come up with anything else.

Comment: If you add a diagram it will be easier to understand the problem without investigation...

Comment: $A$ and the midpoint of $\overline{BC}$ determine a line parallel to the axis of the parabola. Using the reflection property at $B$ and $C$, you can find the focus. Then constructing directrix is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Consider C as the vertex of parabola.  Now draw the diameter BC, find it's midpoint. The line LU connecting  midpoint and A is parallel to the axis of symmetry of  parabola, therefore it is perpendicular to  it's directrix.  A  line  L passing C, the vertex of parabola, and perpendicular to LU is the locus of points, including A, from which two tangents can be drawn on parabola such that AF is always perpendicular at one of these two tangent(F is supposed to be the focus). When A is coincident on C, CF is the axis of symmetry of parabola $L_1'$. So the line $L'_1$ passing C and parallel to LU is the axis of symmetry of parabola. For the focus Draw a perpendicular from A to AB, it intersects the axis of symmetry  $L_1'$ at F which is the focus. The rest is easy; the distance form directrix and vertex v is equal to measure of CF, in this way you can also draw the dirctrix.

Comment: You seem to be working entirely from the assumed parabola $y^2=2px$. Since we don't actually have that parabola handy, you can't simply "draw another diameter parallel to BC" because you can't know its endpoints. (That said, the midpoint of $\overline{BC}$ is certainly known from the given information, as is the point where the given tangent lines intersect; it happens that the lines through these points is parallel to the parabola's axis, so the parallel diameter isn't needed.) And you can't build constructions relative to the vertex without first constructing it from the given info.

Comment: @Blue, you are right. I edited my answer.

Comment: There's no reason to believe that that $C$ is the vertex.

Comment: Blue, See intersections of a tangent and perpendicular from focus in Wiki. parabola

Comment: I don't see the relevance of your comment. Points $B$ and $C$ can be chosen arbitrarily. Neither is necessarily the vertex of the parabola.